# Mobile app on phonegap and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile

I wanna build an app something like mobile messanger. But i'm not quite a programmer. I mean, i know js in the middle level but i have not used it for something serius. 
Anyway, the basic idea that i need to be done in the app is push massages or something like that. Let's imagine that one app's user turn on flashlight on mobile phone of other user. And othe user can do the same thing in other direction or with any contact's nubers who have this app. In other words i need to seending some code from one client to another.

I do not want to grow a beard while learning Cbjective C or Java. I just want my app. And obviously it will be on phonegap with node js.

My question is not like that "please write the code for me". But if someone can tell something about it or give some links or keywords for googling then i will be very happy.

At the now momment i have smooth imagination about the indentification of user, then sending the massage, then server searching othe user, then sending them the message... and in the other direction.
There may be some standard technique for such things?
PS: Sorry for my eanglish.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be to broad and open for interpretation. The answers you get may be based on opinionated, rather then helpful solutions based on a specific technical problem. It's probably best to recreate your question with more specific information. Try something specific, document what you did, then post specific technical questions here.

Generally speaking, I'd create some back-end service that saves and serves up messages between each chatter/participant, and call that service with javascript utilizing JSON as the data to pass back and forth. That's just one way. There's too many different ways to describe here. My answer is just me simply trying to be helpful. However, this question might get closed for being to opinion based. But that's my 2 cents.